# how to set DOCTRINE MAKE:ENTITY to use ANNOTATIONS in SYMFONY 5.4?

Tags: web-development-server, symfony5, php-8.1, symfony5.4, jobeet

I am new to symfony, and I am trying to make MySQL entities using the command :

```
symfony console make:entity
```

But it generates automatically using the ATTRIBUTES, how can I switch that to using ANNOTATIONS ?

I tried using the following command, but it didn't work for me:

```
symfony console make:entity --format:annotations
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`symfony console make:entity --format=annotation`